# ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

Tags: python, pytorch

Python 3.11.1 , With stable version of PyTorch

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
```

[image]

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com, https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch
```

[image]

[image]

Python 3.11.1 , even with nightly version of PyTorch

```
!pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu117
```

[image]

How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But anyway, PyTorch must/should support comtemporary version of Python: 3.11.1 .

```py
py -3.10 -V
python 3.10.9
py -3.10 -m venv vy310
vy310\Scripts\activative
py -V
py –list

pip install jupyterlab

pip install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu117

jupyter lab
```

Answer (score 2):

temporary

```
pip install --pre torch -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu/torch_nightly.html
```

Work with Python 3.11 only. See https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/86566#issuecomment-1419472838

Answer (score 0):

As of Oct 4 2023, this issue has been solved for Python 3.11 ([issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/86566)). However, Python 3.12 just came out and it is now having the same problem ([issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/114893)).